# In Unreal C++ why are structs added to a TArray in an async thread not removed from RAM?

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, struct, unreal-engine4

I am asking this question from an Unreal Engine C++ code point of view but I am wondering if my problem is more to do with the nuances of C++'s way of operating.

I have a Unreal actor. A simple class that holds an array of my own structs and runs a timer which triggers my own function. This function passes a reference of the actors array to an asynchronous task.

This async task then goes to work, first creating a new struct, then adding two floats to its own internal TArray of floats and then adds that struct to the main actors array.

**The problem:**

After the async task has completed and I delete the actor from the level editor window, the system RAM is decreased as I call the Empty() function on the main actors array in the Destroyed() function but the RAM used by all of the structs (ie: The float array inside each struct) is left in memory and never cleared out.

**Observations:**

1. If I do not use an async task and run the same function inside the main thread ALL of the memory is cleared successfully.
2. If I do not create the struct inside the async task and instead initalize the array with a load of structs which in turn are initialized with N number of floats inside the main thread, then pass that as a reference to the async task which works on the data, then the memory is also cleared out successfully.

**What I would like to happen**

I would like to pass a reference of the main actors array of structs to the async task. The async task would then go to work creating the data. Once it is complete, the main actor would then have access to the data and when the actor is deleted in the level editor window, ALL of the memory would be freed.

**The code:**

*The definition of the data struct I am using:*

```
struct FMyDataStruct
{
    TArray<float> ArrayOfFloats;
     
    FMyDataStruct()
    {
        ArrayOfFloats.Empty();
        ArrayOfFloats.Shrink();
    }

    FMyDataStruct(int32 FloatCount)
    {
        ArrayOfFloats.Init(0.f, FloatCount);
    }

    ~FMyDataStruct()
    {
        ArrayOfFloats.Empty();
        ArrayOfFloats.Shrink();
    }
};
```

*The main actors definition of the array I am using:*

```
TArray<FMyDataStruct> MyMainArray;
```

*The main actors custom function I am running:*

```
//CODE 1: This part DOES empty the RAM when run (ie: Run on main thread)
/*for (int32 Index = 0; Index < 50000000; Index++)
{
    FMyDataStruct MyDataStruct;
    MyDataStruct.ArrayOfFloats.Add(FMath::Rand());
    MyDataStruct.ArrayOfFloats.Add(FMath::Rand());
    MyMainArray.Add(MyDataStruct);
}*/
 
//CODE 2: This does NOT empty the RAM when run. The two floats * 50,000,000 are left in system memory after the actor is deleted.
auto Result = Async(EAsyncExecution::Thread, [&]()
{
    for (int32 Index = 0; Index < 50000000; Index++)
    {
        FMyDataStruct MyDataStruct;
        MyDataStruct.ArrayOfFloats.Add(FMath::Rand());
        MyDataStruct.ArrayOfFloats.Add(FMath::Rand());
        MyMainArray.Add(MyDataStruct);
    }
});
```

*An example of initializing the array in the main thread, then working on it inside the async task:*

```
//Initialize the array and its structs (plus the float array inside the struct)
MyMainArray.Init(FMyDataStruct(2), 50000000);

//TFuture/Async task
auto Result = Async(EAsyncExecution::Thread, [Self]()
{
    for (int32 Index = 0; Index < 50000000; Index++)
    {
        Self->MyMainArray[Index].ArrayOfFloats[0] = FMath::Rand();
        Self->MyMainArray[Index].ArrayOfFloats[1] = FMath::Rand();
    }

    //Call the main threads task completed function
    AsyncTask(ENamedThreads::GameThread, [Self]()
    {
        if (Self != nullptr)
        {
            Self->MyTaskComplete();
        }
    });
});
```

**Final thoughts:**

Ultimately what I am asking is can anyone explain to me why from a C++ point of view the structs and their data would be removed from memory successfully when created/added from the main thread but then not removed from memory if created inside the async task/thread?

**Update #1:**

*Here is a minimum reproducible example:*

1. Create a new project in either Unreal Engine 4.23, 4.24 or 4.25.
2. Add a new C++ actor to the project and name it "MyActor".
3. Edit the source with the following:

*MyActor.h*

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "MyActor.generated.h"

struct FMyDataStruct
{
    FMyDataStruct()
    {
        //Default Constructor
    }

    FMyDataStruct(const FMyDataStruct& other)
        : ArrayOfFloats(other.ArrayOfFloats)
    {
        //Copy constructor
    }

    FMyDataStruct(FMyDataStruct&& other)
    {
        //Move constructor
        if (this != &other)
        {
            ArrayOfFloats = MoveTemp(other.ArrayOfFloats);
        }
    }

    FMyDataStruct& operator=(const FMyDataStruct& other)
    {
        //Copy assignment operator
        if (this != &other) //avoid self assignment
        {
            ArrayOfFloats = other.ArrayOfFloats; //UE4 TArray deep copy
        }

        return *this;
    }

    FMyDataStruct& operator=(FMyDataStruct&& other)
    {
        //Move assignment operator
        if (this != &other) //avoid self assignment
        {
            ArrayOfFloats = MoveTemp(other.ArrayOfFloats);
        }

        return *this;
    }

    FMyDataStruct(int32 FloatCount)
    {
        //Custom constructor to initialize the float array
        if (FloatCount > 0)
        {
            ArrayOfFloats.Init(0.f, FloatCount);
        }
    }

    ~FMyDataStruct()
    {
        //Destructor
        ArrayOfFloats.Empty();
        ArrayOfFloats.Shrink();
    }

public:
    TArray<float> ArrayOfFloats;
};

UCLASS()
class BASICPROJECT1_API AMyActor : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
    
public: 
    AMyActor();

protected:
    virtual void Destroyed() override;

public: 
    bool IsEditorOnly() const override;
    bool ShouldTickIfViewportsOnly() const override;
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

    void DoSomething();
    void AsyncTaskComplete();

    bool bShouldCount = true;
    float TimeCounter = 0.f;
    TArray<FMyDataStruct> MyMainArray;
};
```

*MyActor.cpp*

```
#include "MyActor.h"

AMyActor::AMyActor()
{
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;
}

void AMyActor::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    if (!HasAnyFlags(RF_ClassDefaultObject)) //Check for not CDO. We only want to run in the instance
    {
        if (bShouldCount)
        {
            TimeCounter += DeltaTime;

            if (TimeCounter >= 5.f)
            {
                bShouldCount = false;
                DoSomething();
            }
        }
    }
}

void AMyActor::Destroyed()
{
    Super::Destroyed();

    MyMainArray.Empty();
    MyMainArray.Shrink();

    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Actor got Destroyed!"));
}

bool AMyActor::IsEditorOnly() const
{
    return true;
}

bool AMyActor::ShouldTickIfViewportsOnly() const
{
    return true;
}

void AMyActor::DoSomething()
{
    //Change the code that is run:
    //1 = Main thread only
    //2 = Async only
    //3 = Init on main thread and process in async task
    //======================
    int32 CODE_SAMPLE = 1;

    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Actor is running DoSomething()"));

    TWeakObjectPtr<AMyActor> Self = this;


    if (CODE_SAMPLE == 1)
    {
        //CODE 1: Run on main thread. This part DOES empty the RAM when run. BLOCKS the editor window.
        //=========================================================================
        MyMainArray.Empty();
        MyMainArray.Shrink();
        MyMainArray.Reserve(50000000);

        for (int32 Index = 0; Index < 50000000; Index++)
        {
            FMyDataStruct MyDataStruct;
            MyDataStruct.ArrayOfFloats.Reserve(2);
            MyDataStruct.ArrayOfFloats.Emplace(FMath::Rand());
            MyDataStruct.ArrayOfFloats.Emplace(FMath::Rand());
            
            MyMainArray.Emplace(MyDataStruct);
        }

        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Main thread array fill is complete!"));
    }
    else if (CODE_SAMPLE == 2)
    {
        //CODE 2: Run on async task. This does NOT empty the RAM when run
        //(4 bytes per float * 2 floats * 50,000,000 structs = 400Mb is left in system memory after the actor is deleted)
        //=========================================================================
        auto Result = Async(EAsyncExecution::Thread, [Self]()
            {
                if (Self != nullptr)
                {
                    Self->MyMainArray.Empty();
                    Self->MyMainArray.Shrink();
                    Self->MyMainArray.Reserve(50000000);

                    for (int32 Index = 0; Index < 50000000; Index++)
                    {
                        FMyDataStruct MyDataStruct;
                        MyDataStruct.ArrayOfFloats.Reserve(2);
                        MyDataStruct.ArrayOfFloats.Emplace(FMath::Rand());
                        MyDataStruct.ArrayOfFloats.Emplace(FMath::Rand());

                        Self->MyMainArray.Emplace(MyDataStruct);
                    }

                    AsyncTask(ENamedThreads::GameThread, [Self]()
                        {
                            if (Self != nullptr)
                            {
                                Self->AsyncTaskComplete();
                            }
                        });
                }
            });
    }
    else if (CODE_SAMPLE == 3)
    {
        //CODE 3: Initialize the array in the main thread and work on the data in the async task
        //=========================================================================
        MyMainArray.Init(FMyDataStruct(2), 50000000);

        auto Result = Async(EAsyncExecution::Thread, [Self]()
            {
                if (Self != nullptr)
                {
                    for (int32 Index = 0; Index < 50000000; Index++)
                    {
                        Self->MyMainArray[Index].ArrayOfFloats[0] = FMath::Rand();
                        Self->MyMainArray[Index].ArrayOfFloats[1] = FMath::Rand();
                    }

                    AsyncTask(ENamedThreads::GameThread, [Self]()
                        {
                            if (Self != nullptr)
                            {
                                Self->AsyncTaskComplete();
                            }
                        });
                }
            });
    }
}

void AMyActor::AsyncTaskComplete()
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Async task is complete!"));
}
```

4. Compile and run the project.
5. Drag the actor into the level editor window.
6. After 5 seconds the code will run and the RAM usage will increase to 1750Mb.
7. Select the actor in the outliner window and delete it.
8. The RAM usage will perform like this:

***CODE 1:** RAM is cleared out all the way to the starting RAM usage of 650Mb.*

***CODE 2:** RAM is cleared down to 1000Mb and never returns to starting usage.*

***CODE 3:** RAM is cleared out all the way to the starting RAM usage of 650Mb.*

I thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm curious how to determined that the memory is still in use.

Comment: I used Windows Task Manager as it displays the memory usage per app and as I am adding 50 million structs to the array the RAM jumps from 700Mb before adding the actor to 1800Mb after the array is full but then once the actor is deleted the ram settles at 1100Mb. Even after waiting 10 minutes for the garbage collector to run it still does not clear out the ram back down to 700Mb.

Comment: That difference of 400Mb equals 4 bytes per float * 2 floats * 50,000,000 structs = 400Mb.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] and provide that as part of your question. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @3Dev There is no garbage collector in C++. And an application is not required to release memory that it no longer uses, it can hold on to it for future allocations if it wants. `free` and `delete` might actually keep the memory in reserve. Memory is also usually provided to the process in chunks, and if any byte in that chunk is still in use it cannot be release to the OS even if it's mostly unused. There could be a lot of reasons for the Task Manager to be showing that the process is using more memory. The Task Manager isn't enough to indicate that there is definitively a memory leak.

Comment: If there is a memory leak, running the test a large number of times should show the total memory requirement continually increase. Otherwise, you can try using memory tracking tools like valgrind or instrument `operator new` and `operator delete` to try to track memory consumption.

Comment: Any difference if you use `TaskGraph` or `ThreadPool`?

Comment: It also shouldn't add up to 400Mb, because a `TArray` has data members as well.

Comment: @Rotem No difference. Thread/ThreadPool/TaskGraph all keep hold of the memory. The TArray is being emptied. In the Destroyed() function of the actor when the actor is deleted it runs the MyMainArray.Empty() and Shrink() to try and get the memory down which does clear out the array (ie Num() elements is zero). But the RAM from all those floats seems to be left behind).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The garbage collector I am talking about is the Unreal Engine garbage collector. TArrays are Unreals version of arrays. I also tried using std::vector with reserve and push_back but that just had the same problem as TArray. Also, the memory problem does accumulate so every actor that is dragged in, then the async task run, then the actor deleted does add up RAM everytime.

Comment: FMyDataStruct violates the rule of three, leading to undefined behaior, which may include memory leaks

Comment: @MooingDuck I corrected the FMyDataStruct and it made no difference.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I have added Update #1 to my question with a full Minimum Reproducible Example so that others can see the problem for themselves.

Comment: No, there's no `main()`. Please, that minimal example should only be one file usually and be compilable without making changes. Just copy the code, compile it and run it, that should be the goal.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt There's no main() because its an Unreal Engine actor class not a C++ program. What I have provided allows for anyone to copy the code, paste it into an actors source and compile/run.

Comment: The "move constructors" aren't actually move constructors, so I would expect those to cause chaos

Comment: @MooingDuck You mean they are not move constructors because I missed out the "&&" and put "&" instead? From the Unreal documentation: "TArray also supports move semantics, which can be invoked using the MoveTemp function. After a move, the source array is guaranteed to be left empty". I have updated the code above with what looks right to me. It made no difference to the RAM not being cleared. Thanks.

Comment: possibly off topic (with the mention that I am not familiar with UE): if you feel the need to write custom copy/move members and destructors then you are most likely doing something wrong. Read about the [rule of zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: @bolov The reason I included those things is because I needed to init the array of structs with each struct containing two floats. Then because I had added a constructor then Mooing Duck mentioned the rule of three so I went ahead and included all from the rule of five. I have now removed everything so it is just a plain struct with one TArray of floats inside of it. This also leaves behind memory when the actor is deleted. The interesting part is the struct works because if I run the code on the main thread all the data gets deleted with the actor. The same code in async does not. Thanks :)

Comment: The same issue is happening to me (UE 5.2) actually debugging a marketplace plugin. Noticed RAM significantly increased after using it, and the plugin uses AsyncTask and a lambda that captures some data structures by value.  Looking at Engine source for AsyncTask, I couldn't see when these tasks were destructed so seems the lambda captures stay in memory with the task forever.  Doing an Unreal Insights memory capture and leak detection confirms it. Many TaskGraph instances show up.